# Haskell : recursive data type (Parameterized Types)

Tags: haskell

I have this :

```
data Val s i a = S s | I i | A a deriving (Show)
```

To play with non-homogenous lists in Haskell. So I can do something like (just an example function ):

```
oneDown :: Val String Int [String]-> Either String String
```

But I would actually like this to be a list of Vals, i.e. something like :

```
oneDown :: Val String Int [Val]-> Either String String
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What would you like to be a list of Val's? What do you want oneDown to do?

Comment: @jberryman I would like Val's to be a recursive data structure which can have lists of itself not just list of Strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for would result in an infinite data type, which Haskell explicitly disallows. However, we can hide this infinity behind a newtype and the compiler won't complain.

```
data Val s i a = S s | I i | A a deriving (Show)
newtype Val' = Val' (Val String Int [Val']) deriving (Show)
```

It's still doing exactly what your example did (plus a few type constructors that will get optimized away at runtime), but now we can infinitely recurse because we've *guarded* the recursive type.

This is actually what the [recursion-schemes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes) library does to get inductively-defined data that we can define generic recursion techniques on. If you're interested in generalized data types like this, you may have a look at that library.

To construct this newly-made type, we have to use the `Val'` constructor.

```
let myVal = A [Val' (I 3), Val' (S "ABC"), Val' (A [])]
```